# Larvel-mix + Pinia throws an error: getActivePinia was called with no active Pinia

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-mix, pinia

I am using `laravel-mix` to bundle my Vue 3 and Pinia code. My `app.js` looks like this:

```js
require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from "pinia";

const pinia = createPinia();
const app = createApp({});

app.use(pinia);
// ...
// ...
// ...
app.mount('#app');
```

The code in my Vue components is basic and NOT different from what is in the Pinia documentation https://pinia.vuejs.org/introduction.html#basic-example

However even though the `laravel-mix` sucessfuly compiled and bundled everything, the result page shows this error in the browser console:

```
getActivePinia was called with no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?
    const pinia = createPinia()
    app.use(pinia)
This will fail in production.
```

Comment: According to [pinia docs](https://pinia.vuejs.org/getting-started.html#installation) isn't  a component `App.vue` missing when you are initializing `app`?

Comment: @A.Z I only removed that line and other lines for better reading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This did the trick for me - use [`setActivePinia(pinia)`](https://pinia.vuejs.org/api/modules/pinia.html#setactivepinia) right after `const pinia = createPinia();`

```js
import { createPinia, setActivePinia } from "pinia"
const pinia = createPinia();
setActivePinia(pinia);
```

Because you're using Pinia in a SSR environment (Laravel), the process of setting up Pinia is a bit different from what is in the docs

1. Create a file `\store\store.js` which will serve as a starting point for Pinia:

```js
import { createPinia, setActivePinia } from "pinia";
const pinia = createPinia();
setActivePinia(pinia);
export default pinia;
```

2. In `app.js`, import the `pinia` (exported from `\store\store.js`) and configure your app to use it:

```js
require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import pinia from './store/store' // importing Pinia
// import your components here

const app = createApp({});
app.use(pinia);
// ... use your components here
// ...
// ...
app.mount('#app');
```

3. Pinia-business as usual